# Upgrading from Django 1.3 (Python 2.6) to Django 1.5 + Python 2.7 CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, mod-wsgi

We currently have a server running python2.6 + apache and mod_wsgi that runs with Django 1.3.

I plan to use the following guide to install python 2.7 http://toomuchdata.com/2012/06/25/how-to-install-python-2-7-3-on-centos-6-2/.

Then use pip to install the packages for 2.7 which I believe using pip install after installing python2.7 will handle this.

After this I think recompiling mod_wsgi with it pointing to the python2.7 path should handle making Apache2 load the correct version of python for the site.

I was just wondering if I have missed something or whether this process is completely wrong and shouldn't be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Why use 2.7? Django 1.5 works with 2.6 too and you don't need to do all this extra work.

Comment: The 2.6 version currently in use is an outdated version of 2.6 so my thinking is along the lines of if I should upgrade the python version I might as well jump to 2.7.3

Comment: What's outdated about it? RHEL/Centos provide updated 2.6 packages with bugfixes and security updates.

Comment: Well it was manually compiled by the people who set it up originally and is python 2.6.2 - being manually compiled I assume it isn't easy at all to upgrade. I should note the CentOS version is 5.7

Comment: Ah, centos 5. That ships with an ancient python. To be honest, I think it'll be faster to reinstall with centos 6 (comes with python 2.6) than to compile your own python.

Comment: Heh I wish I could! :)

Comment: Why not use the IUS repository and do a `yum install python27` ?

Comment: Honestly never knew about that, I'll look into it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for an actual answer to your question: If you use mod_wsgi in embedded mode, you will need to recompile it. But I'd suggest running it in daemon mode, so you don't have to recompile mod_wsgi (or restart apache whenever you app changes, just the wsgi daemon)

Comment: And if you go this route, I recommend uwsgi as daemon/container. I use nginx+uwsgi myself and it works beautifully.